# How did this non-privileged user get into the Suggested Edits queue?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Looking at the review queue, I just happened to tap on one of the user's avatars in the list of recent reviewers:

[image]

After tapping on it, I came to the [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1308332/bonny):

[image]

Wait... **419 rep**? The user is 1581 reputation away from being able to get in! How did this happen?

Comment: *I feel so famous for having my picture up there (not as bonny).* Also, I think you ought to double check your maths there...

Comment: @hayden Woops... :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I too was in this situation once: my first Custodian badge was awarded for reviewing a suggested edit when I had just over 200 reputation.

This is possible if someone with [under 2,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) edits a post of yours, you get notified to review it (note: users with 2,000 or more reputation can bypass this as they do not need their edits reviewed). This happens regardless of how much reputation you have, and it's nice that you as the author of the question are allowed to review such edits in case they're invalid.

I believe this is the only review type a user can *participate* in (albeit in a very limited way) without first requiring a certain amount of reputation.

Answer (score 12):

Look at every single one of the [user's](http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/462743) [suggested](http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/543877) [edit](http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1909105) [reviews](http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/215904). They are all on his own posts!

The user probably went to one of his own posts and saw `edit (1)`, and clicked it out of curiosity. They were then presented with the typical review pane.

It seems that even the users with <2K can review edits on their own posts.

Comment: The first time I saw that was that a user edited his post while not logged in, noticed that, logged in and was probably surprised that he could accept his own edit.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Hah!

Comment: You get notified when an edit is suggested on one of your own posts. With a link to "please review it".

Comment: @Tin Yes - the edit queue is so fast anyway on SO that I never click the notification quickly enough.

Comment: I'm confused why you were confused about this. It is a feature. An OP can *always* insta-accept an edit to their own post (and technically they do have *full edit privileges* on their own posts).

Comment: @animuson I'm not confused - I just didn't know about it. After some research, I do.