# 900 reputation user review a task that requires 2k

Tags: support, reputation, review

How could a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/926884/soryngod) with 980 reputation points review a task from the *Suggested Edits* review queue, which requires at least 2k reputation?

[image]

Please understand that I have nothing personal against him; I'm just asking to understand how it's possible.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I'm suggesting an edit to your question so you can see how this would work. You should get a notification about it, and then you can come here to the question to review my edit.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Thank you for showing me how it works(and fixing my bad english).

Comment: @kiamaluno The idea was for DontVoteMeDown to come review the edit :p

Comment: See [the more related dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181246/how-did-this-non-privileged-user-get-into-the-suggested-edits-queue/181247#181247).

Comment: @Undo yeah, that answer is more explanative too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The owner of the post can review suggested edits to their post (with a binding vote, even) at any reputation level. Those still count as reviews as far as the queue is concerned.

Comment: But he can accept or decline it?

Comment: Yes, the OP has all the same options to Approve, Reject, or Edit as a normal 2k reviewer does.

Comment: I never know that, not even know how to do it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown usually (on stack overflow at least) the review happens so quickly the OP never gets a chance to review